# Can I track the ??? Rathian on investigations?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

The handler said to do expeditions or optional quests to track the ??? Rathian. Is it also possible to progress tracking progress on investigations?

Comment: Are you referring to research level of the monster?

Comment: @n_palum Not in the same way as you research other monsters, although it's related since you gather tracks the same way. There's a specific overarching quest for the ??? Rathian, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible. This is how I tracked the ??? (Pink) Rathian, as I prefer to do Investigations for the zenny.

As noted in the comments, the Investigations must be High Rank for you to find tracks for this quest.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was hoping to hear. Need to squeeze every reward I can out of these hunts to gear up :)

Comment: Might be a good idea to note that those investigations must be high ranked